# Ubuntu can never see my data partition on startup. I have to click the icon on the launcher and then it works fine until I restart

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

I personally locked the icon for the partition to the launcher.

This may have started happening after I copied and pasted the partitions to my current SSD.

Comment: You need to add an entry to the /etc/fstab file that will mount it for you on every reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to edit `/etc/fstab` to make it auto-mount at boot time. Something similar to:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo blkid # to obtain the correct UUID number
sudo mkdir /media/username/some_mountpoint_name # for drives owned by root
sudo chown username: /media/username/some_mountpoint_name # for drives owned by username
```

and add something similar to one of these to `/etc/fstab`...

In `terminal`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab

# shared EXT4 disk
UUID=correct_UUID_# /media/username/some_mountpoint_name   EXT4      defaults   0    2

# shared ntfs disk
UUID=correct_UUID_# /media/username/some_mountpoint_name   ntfs-3g   defaults   0    0
```